kafka Kraft Production setup ( one node is down another broker also getting down)
Kraft cluster 3 node i am using  .If one node is down another broker is also getting down.
Do we need configure any additional configuration for production environment?
data replication also not happening.
Kindly request you suggest or provide the sample configuration.
